# Change Scroll Position of JTable inside JInteranlFrame

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JTable` inside `JScrollPane` inside `JInternalFrame`.
How can I change the scroll position of `JTable`

Following is my code:

```
private void scrollToNewRow(JTable table, int row, int col) {
    if (table.getParent() != null) {
        if (table.getParent() instanceof JScrollPane) {
            JScrollPane sp = (JScrollPane) table.getParent();
            if (sp == null)
                return;
            JViewport viewport = sp.getViewport();
            Rectangle r = table.getCellRect(row, col, true);
            Point p = viewport.getViewPosition();
            r.setLocation(r.x - p.x, r.y - p.y + table.getRowHeight());
            viewport.scrollRectToVisible(r);
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not working.
But one thing when i apply same code in `JFrame` it works perfectly. Please suggest me how i can achieve this in `JInternalFrame`.

Comment: I appreciate images for swing question, But do you have enough rows in table to scroll?

Comment: @Sarz yes i have rows because firstly i select that particular row and then call scrolltoNewRow function

Comment: maybe show how you create the table, scrollpane and internal frame and what operation you are doing to invoke this method.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me. Here is the sample code I wrote (in a rush, just testing material - and sorry, not commented):

```
public class InternalFrameTest extends JFrame
{
    public InternalFrameTest()
    {
        setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        final JDesktopPane dp = new JDesktopPane();
        final JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("Toto");
        dp.add(internalFrame);
        internalFrame.setBounds(10, 10, 700, 500);
        Vector<Vector<String>> data = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
        Vector<String> columns = new Vector<String>();
        columns.addElement("name");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Vector<String> elem = new Vector<String>();
            elem.addElement("" + i);
            data.addElement(elem);
        }
        final JTable table = new JTable(data, columns);
        final JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);
        internalFrame.add(sp);
        internalFrame.show();
        final JButton b = new JButton("GO!");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent pEvent)
            {
                JViewport viewport = sp.getViewport();
                Rectangle r = table.getCellRect(50, 1, true);
                Point p = viewport.getViewPosition();
                r.setLocation(r.x - p.x, r.y - p.y + table.getRowHeight());
                viewport.scrollRectToVisible(r);
            }
        });
        panel.add(dp, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
        panel.add(b, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new InternalFrameTest();
    }
}
```

Clicking on the button does scroll the table to the required cell.
Maybe more detail on the rest of your code could help. But that part of the code is probably not the problem.

Comment: so sorry i have posted some wrong code i just checking by making hardcode values for rectangle.
it has not work even if i use below code 
`viewport.scrollRectToVisible(r);`

Comment: i haven't Understand what you have written in these lines because you firstly created a InternalFrame and then add that Scrollpane to that Internal Frame that is fine , but at the end what you have done you just add scroll pane (sp) directly to JPanel which is associated with JFrame.
I don't think so it matches my code.

Comment: Indeed. Fixed (and tested, it still works and scrolls to the correct cell). The intent was to add the JDesktopPane (and I have fixed the constraints as well so that it fills the space). Sorry!